# How is a mass, suspended vertically by two springs in parallel, kept stable?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, spring

Consider a mass suspended vertically from above by two springs in parallel with different spring constants. Wouldn't the tension be different in each spring? How is this system kept in equilibrium?

Comment: Yes the tensions would be different in the two springs, and the two tensions would add up to $mg$, where $m$ is the mass of the object. Why would this present any problems with stability?

Comment: Perhaps the extensions (and the unextended lengths) are different? Is this what's confusing you?

Comment: I realise that it was a stable system, and I just wanted to clarify my understanding of what's going on in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

I've simulated the case

[image]

The two springs had the same initial length, and the block in the picture is in equilibrium. See how it is deviated towards the spring with bigger stiffness to decrease the resultant moment, and stop the rotation of the block.

Answer (score 1):

The thing that the springs must have in common is their length $x$. This comes from the mass which is attached to the springs, having different lengths does not make sense in this setup.

From this you can compute the forces. Say the spring constants are $k_1$ and $k_2$. Then the net force exerted is $k_1 x + k_2 x$. In equilibrium, this matches the gravitational force $mg$. Then you have $mg = (k_1 + k_2) x$ which seems to have exactly one solution at
$$ x = \frac{mg}{k_1 + k_2} \,.$$

I do not think that anything is unstable here. Sure, the force that each spring exerts is different. They are $F_i = k_i x$. For different spring constants $k_i$, each spring contributes a different force. The stiffer spring (higher $k_i$) will also exert more force.

Comment: Say that the mass is a cuboidal block, that the springs are attached to the mass some distance apart, and that one spring is a lot less stiff than the other. Is the extension in both springs still the same? Why?

Comment: This is just plain wrong - see Tofaili's diagram.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: What is wrong? My answer or the first comment?

Comment: The claim that the two springs will stretch to the same length is wrong.   That would imply different net forces, which is possible if you attach the springs such that the torques about the two attachment points  are in the ratio of the spring constants (i.e. the weaker spring is farther from the center of mass), but in the general case the springs will stretch different amounts.

Comment: I see. My assumption was that we have a point-mass and the two springs are attached at the same point in the ceiling and also on the point. The springs would then be overlapping. It does not make much sense if one wants to realize that. It is also against the diagram in Tofaili's answer. Perhaps my answer is the “spherical cows in vacuum” one here? :-)